# Second moment for minimum number of uniform random variables required to cross a threshold

Tags: probability

Let $N(x) = \min\{n: U_1 + U_2 + \ldots + U_n > x\}$, where $U_i \sim Uniform[0, 1]$. There is a nice discussion about calculating $E[N(x)]$ [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10567/number-of-uniform-rvs-needed-to-cross-a-threshold/10568). I am interested in  $E[N(x)^2]$ and it seems like $E[N(x)^2] \approx 4x^2$ for large x. Can somebody guide how to calculate asymptotic approximation or exact expression for $E[N(x)^2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick way to obtain (rough) **bounds** for $\mathbb{E}[N(x)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[N(x)]^2$. Let $S_n=\sum_{i\le n}U_i$, $\mathbb{E}U_1=\mu$, $\mathbb{E}U_1^2=\mu_2$, and $Var(U_1)=\sigma^2$. Using Wald's identities, we have

$$
\mathbb{E}S_{N(x)}=\mu\mathbb{E}N(x), \quad \text{and}\quad \mathbb{E}[S_{N(x)}-\mu N(x)]^2=\sigma^2\mathbb{E}N(x).
$$

Then, noticing that $\mathbb{E}S_N\in (x,x+\mu]$ and $\mathbb{E}S_N^2\in (x^2,x^2+2\mu x+\mu_2]$, for any $x\ge 0$,

\begin{align*}
2x\le &\mathbb{E}[N(x)] \le 2x+1,  \quad \text{and} \\
4x^2-\frac{10}{3}x-\frac{4}{3}\le &\mathbb{E}[N(x)]^2 \le 4x^2+\frac{38}{3}x+\frac{13}{3}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Can you add more details for why $\mathbb{E}S_N\in (x,x+\mu]$ and $\mathbb{E}S_N^2\in (x^2,x^2+2\mu x+\sigma^2]$?

Comment: In the expansion for $\mathbb{E}[S_{N(x)}-\mu N(x)]^2$, we have $\mathbb{E}[N(x) S_{N(x)}]$, it seems like we need upper and lower bound on it. Please add more details.

Comment: @vdesai (1) $S_{N(x)}>x$ and $\mathbb{E}S_{N(x)}=\mathbb{E}S_{N(x)-1}+\mathbb{E}U_{N(x)}\le x+\mu$.

Comment: (2) $S_{N(x)}^2>x^2$ and $\mathbb{E}S_{N(x)}^2=\mathbb{E}S_{N(x)-1}^2+2\mathbb{E}S_{N(x)-1}U_N+\mathbb{E}U_{N(x)}^2\le x^2+2x\mu+\mu_2$.

Comment: (3) $2x^2\le\mathbb{E}[S_{N(x)}N(x)]\le(x+1)(2x+1)$.